# How does author derives $\cos \theta = \frac{dx}{ds} \qquad \sin\theta = \frac{dy }{ds}, $?

Tags: classical-mechanics

In the book of *Dynamics* by Horace Lamb, at page 103, is it given

> that for a motion on a smooth curve, the equation of motion is given
>   by  $$mv \frac{dv }{ ds} = -mg \sin \theta  \qquad \frac{ mv^2 }{r} =
>  -mg \cos\theta + R, $$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the surface normal and vertical direction, and $R$ is the "pressure" exerted by
>   the curve.
>
> [...]
>
> Then, we have  $$\cos \theta = \frac{dx}{ds} \qquad \sin\theta =
>  \frac{dy  }{ds},  $$ where $s$ is length of the path taken over the
>   surface, and $x,y$ are usual cartesian coordinates as $y$ is taken as
>   upward.

However, I cannot understand how does the author derives the latter equations between $\theta$ and the derivatives of $x,y$ wrt $s$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Write it as $dx=ds\cos\theta$ and $dy=ds\sin\theta$. It is just a decomposition of $ds$ into components along $x$ and $y$ axes

Comment: but the path is not a straight line; even though we can approximate it to be like that.

Comment: The full path is not straight, but a small element $ds$ can be considered as such.

Comment: Can we assure ourselves that such a consideration will lead us to the correct equation of motion in the global case ? i.e the variation will go to zero, and not to infinity ?

Comment: Yes. In the limit when $ds\to 0$, the path can be considered straight. I forgot to add it to my answer, but if the angle between normal and $y$ axis is $\theta$, then so is the angle between the tangent to the curve (along $ds$) and $x$ axis.

Comment: Unless, of course, you allow discontinuity in the derivative of the path. If the path is smooth, then you are OK

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Now apply the rule of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$